# QThread updating UI statusbar?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, qthread

I have a simple pyqt gui which creates a qthread to open a file and read some information.  I want to update the statusbar of my gui.  Normally, this would be my function call to update a message on the statusbar:

```
class gui1(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(gui1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("hello world")
        ...
        # create thread here
        self.mythread = WorkThread(text)   # create instance and pass some text

        self.mythread.finished.connect(self.threadDone)   # signal emitted on finish of thread
        self.mythread.start()   # begin thread
```

However, the call to update the status within the thread does't work.  How can I update the statusbar for my gui from within the qthread?

```
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self,text):  
        self.text = text
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()        

    def run(self):
        self.ui.statusBar().showMessage(status)   # WRONG SELF

        return  # must return, so that Qthread finished signal is emitted
```

Comment: You need to send do a queued method call on the GUI object (via a signal-slot connection or `QMetaObject.invoke`). It is an error to access the GUI objects from a non-GUI thread.

Comment: best approach is emit signal and connect it to proper slot then qt will handle the rest.

Comment: and i thought all `QThread inheritance nonsence` was removed ... i hope the `PyQt` port uses the same mechanics than the c++ library, then fololow: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must never attempt to update the GUI from outside the GUI thread. Instead, add a custom signal to the worker thread and connect it to a slot in the GUI:

```
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    statusMessage = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)       
    ...

    def run(self):
        self.statusMessage.emit(self.text)

class gui1(QtGui.QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):    
        super(gui1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mythread = WorkThread(text)
        ...
        self.mythread.statusMessage.connect(self.handleStatusMessage)

   @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
   def handleStatusMessage(self, message):
       self.ui.statusBar().showMessage(message)
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case... but why not?  I have successfully passed the self.ui from my GUI and updated my GUI from the qthread.  Somehow I guessed this might be a bad idea, but doing it the right way sure adds a bunch more code to make it work they way I want. :)

Comment: @panofish. I suppose it's more accurate to say "should never" rather than "must never". If you don't do things the right way, it's just not _guaranteed_ to always work properly, and of course there are always the usual thread-safety issues. See the [Threads and QObjects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html) section in the Qt docs for the full story.