# Adding HTML to .setText() crashes the script

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a simple program which displays `QLabels` and updates them with data retrieved elsewhere. Up to now I was using plain text for the update but would like [to use HTML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html).

Specifically the following line (taken out of context) updates a `QLabel`:

```
self.root.calendar_today.setText(r['calendar']['today'])
```

With some text. It works fine.

I just replaced that line with

```
curcal = "<hr>{today}<hr>".format(
                    today=r['calendar']['today']
                )
self.root.calendar_today.setText(curcal)
```

And now the program crashes

[image]

With the following on stderr:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QLabel(0x2f4ed98), parent's thread is QThread(0x2adc7a8), current thread is QThread(0x2f3b418)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x2fb5ea0), parent's thread is QThread(0x2f3b418), current thread is QThread(0x2adc7a8)
```

I have no idea why adding some HTML triggers some messages about threads being created ?

Is there something I should be aware of when using HTML as opposed to plain text in labels?

**EDIT**: I further simplified the example by just replacing the working line with `self.root.calendar_today.setText("<b>hello</b>")` (still crashing)

**EDIT 2**: following [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)'s comments I tried to replace the `QLabel` with a `QTextEdit` widget - same problem (`QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread. (Parent is QTextDocument(0x33c2220), parent's thread is QThread(0x2f06f00), current thread is QThread(0x33dc770)`)

---

## Reason

I indirectly find out where the problem probably is (I started to convert the code while [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro)'s comment popped out).

I was using `QThreads` with the expectation that I can set widgets properties from within them. It turns out that [I was wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22239277/903011) and that I should not have done that, but use signals instead. The code worked for plain text but crashed for HTML, which I guess is one of the mysteries in multithreading.

I rewrote my code to use a few signals and the `QLabel` is updated correctly, with the same code that crashed before.

I am wondering whether to delete this question but I will leave it here in case someone witnesses the same behavior.

Comment: I just tried to use escaped HTML - same thing. What is `setHTML()` ? I did not find any doc on that.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a QLabel, though (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#text-prop)

Comment: The *cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread* message indicates something entirely unrelated is wrong, actually.

Comment: Well, this is why I am surprised. The initial line works fine (the program runs without problems), just switching to HTML in the passed string leads to the crash. This is the only line changed in the whole program.

Comment: Yup, so I'll have to back out as I cannot offer any help with that. Sorry to have weighed in! I cleared out obsolete comments to not clutter up the place.

Comment: You must be kidding - you are always welcome to "weight in" for any of my questions! This extra weight usually leads to the solution :)

Comment: @WoJ. You are obviously using multiple threads in an unsafe way - hence the self-explanatory error message. But clearly it's impossible to offer much more insight than that, since you have omitted all the relevant code.

Comment: @ekhumoro: you are right, I updated my question with the reason. I was in the process of reworking my code when I saw your comment -- BTW the rework is based on another answer of yours (linked). If you would be kind enough to turn your comment into answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests you are using multiple threads in an unsafe way. You should never attempt to directly update gui elements from outside the main thread.

The simplest way to safely communicate between threads is to use signals.